# Images exchange their rows in listview when a List item is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, imageview

I have this strange problem about loading images using AsyncTask in ListView.In my ListView, every row contains an ImageView and a TextView. I followed this link for it:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

The images are being downloaded successfully from the URL and are populated on their respected rows. But when I scroll the ListView or click on any list item, the images just exchange their rows. Though the text in the TextViews remain on the same rows. I don't understand why its happening. I have googled a lot about it but can't find a perfect reason for it. Please help.

Here is my adapter class:

```
     private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> allFriends; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> allFriends, Context context){
        this.allFriends = allFriends;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allFriends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return allFriends.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FriendsViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null||!(convertView instanceof TextView)||!(convertView instanceof ImageView)) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_view, null);

             holder = new FriendsViewHolder();
             holder.friendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
             holder.friendImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendImage);                

             convertView.setTag(holder);
         }else {
             holder = (FriendsViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
         }

        holder.friendName.setText((String) allFriends.get(position).get(FriendsActivity.FRIENDS_NAME_KEY));

        String otherId=(String) allFriends.get(position).get(FriendsActivity.IDKEY);
        String isImage=(String) allFriends.get(position).get(FriendsActivity.IS_IMAGE_KEY);

            if(isImage.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                download(otherId, holder.friendImage);
            }

        return convertView;
    }
}//End of list adapter
```

and the download method is:

```
   public void download(String otherId, ImageView imageView) {
     BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
     task.execute(otherId);
 }
```

Here BitmapDownloaderTask is the async task for downloading the images:

```
    class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private String otherId;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        // Actual download method, run in the task thread
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
             // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.

             return getOtherUserImage(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if(bitmap!=null){
                if (imageViewReference != null) {
                    ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get(); 
                    if(imageView != null ){
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And getOtherUserImage method is:

```
    public Bitmap getOtherUserImage(String otherUserId){

    // code to download the image goes here. It returns bitmap "bmImg".

    if(bmImg==null){
        return null;
    }else {
        bmImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmImg,imageWidth, imageHeight, true);

        /*availableFriends.get(position).put(BITMAP_KEY, bmImg);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });*/
        return bmImg;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you following the view holder approach? Post your custom adapter to see what's going on..

Comment: yes I am following the ViewHolder approach. Please see the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Android Developer's Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) describes how to correctly load images into a ListView asynchronously and provides a great sample app that you should be able to quickly and easily modify (I did) to fit your needs.

> Indeed, for memory efficiency reasons, `ListView` recycles the views
>   that are displayed when the user scrolls. If one flings the list, a
>   given `ImageView` object will be used many times. Each time it is
>   displayed the `ImageView` correctly triggers an image download task,
>   which will eventually change its image. So where is the problem? As
>   with most parallel applications, the key issue is in the ordering. In
>   our case, there's no guarantee that the download tasks will finish in
>   the order in which they were started. The result is that the image
>   finally displayed in the list may come from a previous item, which
>   simply happened to have taken longer to download. This is not an issue
>   if the images you download are bound once and for all to given
>   `ImageViews`.

Comment: I have tried the approach in the above link as well, but its still not working. :( Any more ideas...

Comment: Hi Jeff. I have downloaded the code given in above link and I have implemented exactly like it in my code as well. And I am able to cache the images as well. But the problem of images showing up in the wrong rows still persists. Now it doesn't happen on scrolling because I am using cache. But sometimes while opening the screen for the first time, they show up in wrong places already. In my case I am not using the "url" because I have only one URL on which I have to send the userId and get his image. So I am using Id instead of URL to distinguish the places of images.But no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so I have finally done it. But I have a little problem here. I want to show default image while the image is being loaded. just like in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386411/how-to-show-default-image-while-image-is-being-downloaded-using-asynctask

Comment: @YogeshSomani Can u please tell how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make that method "synchronized" which is downloading the images. A lot of threads are running simultaneously , so there are chances that images go on wrong places.